# How can I determine a person's area based on the camera position?

Tags: opencv, video-processing

I have a surveillance camera who captures people walking around. Video resolution is 640x480.

I know the position of the camera. Let's say it's on a wall 2 meters height above ground and the distance between the camera position and the person with white contour is 10m.

For example in this foto:

[image]

I would like to know if I can determine based on the camera position the optimal contour area for a person in some positions. For example the person with the white contour has the area between 400-1000, the blue one has the area >3000.

More exactly if I have a formula calculating what should be the area of the contour of a normal person from the long plan (eg.the person with white contour)based on the distance where I put my camera (eg. at 5 meters distance, a person from long plan has a area of 800-1000) I can determine if in the long plan I have a crowd (eg: the countur area generated is 1800-2000--> that means we have 2 persons next to each other, identified as 1 big area). I need this formula for a normal person area/distance of the camera to identify if I have one person in the long plan or 2 next to each other.

I want to know before I play the video if a person walks in the same area as the white contour I could know that his area should be between defined interval.

Can I determinate the optimal contour area/ height+width of a person only using the camera position(for example 2 meters height above ground and 10 meters length from the with contour)?

Comment: what do you mean with "person area"? Real life height and width of a person, inpedenpent from its size in the video image? With camera calibration (intrinsic parameters) and knowledge of the ground plane where the peeson is standing, you can compute those values.

Comment: @Micka I edited my post. Maybe now you can understand what I want to do.

Comment: I still dont understand what you want to compute.. The contour's area can be computed with cv::contourArea function. If you want to know hiw big a person will probably be in the imge you can do this with camera calibration, ground plane assumption and knowledge/estimation of the person's rwal life size.

Comment: more exactly how can I do that? is there a mathematical formula? I am using my mobile phone camera for the video, so I don't know the precise calibration. I do know how to determine contour area, I need to determine probability of a person size, exactly how you`ve mentioned. No matter where I put my camera, I want to know how big a person might be in the image (also I edited my post above, once again). If you are available, can we join the chat?

Comment: projection of 3D points  (person top  and person bottom) to the image. Typically this is fome with homogenous coordinates and matrix multiplications to perform the projection.

Comment: if you know/setup  the ground plane in the image you can compute the camera position with solvePnP

Comment: without some kind of calibration I dont know a solution.